# How do I determine how much battery and resistance is required to wire a series of LEDs?

Tags: led, design

I need to wire 5 led's in series with a switch and variable resistor to control brightness.

[These I think](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=3125355)

I think the circuit will need to look something like this (Ignoring the values the editor added!) but it's been a very long time since I've done anything like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj724o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I don't know how to calculate how much battery power will be required, or if it will need additional resistence.

How do you go about solving these kinds of equations?

Comment: I'll put the resistor before the first LED, after the switch

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul How exactly does the position of the resistor matter?

Comment: I'm assuming you will attach the wiper to either end of the potentiometer. You should also add an additional series resistor to set the maximum current allowed when the potentiometer is set to zero ohms. This is the "smallest value of resistance" referred to in Brian's answer. This will protect your LEDs.

Comment: a convention which i am used to, and thats how I [usually](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13746/why-does-a-resistor-need-to-be-on-the-anode-of-an-led) see them in many other schematics.

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul Current flow convention has nothing to do with resistor position convention. Neither is there any recognized convention for which side a resistor goes in, nor does it make the least bit of difference to circuit operation. Your comment merely confuses EE-inexperienced readers, while adding no value whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. Every bit of information is useful, and appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product summary tells you the typical and max. forward voltage and maximum current.

Multiply typical and max. voltages by no. of LEDs, then choose a power source (battery) with higher voltage than max * no. of LEDs.

Subtract typical voltage * no. of LEDs from battery voltage; this is the voltage you can expect across the resistor.

Divide that voltage by the max. operating current to give you the smallest value of resistance you need. You can increase it to reduce brightness.

Comment: That sounds great! I'll run these numbers later today. Really appreciated.

Comment: `Divide that voltage by the max. operating current` How do you determine max operating current?

Comment: See first line of answer. The product summary is on the page you linked to.

Comment: Ohhh ok. Its not modified by the led count then? So sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: actually that's not a dumb question. Since the LEDs are in series, the same current runs though each one. So you don't modify the current but you do modify the voltage. (If you ran them in parallel you would need more current, less voltage, and each would need its own resistor.)

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, it works out to something like this: typical voltage Et = 3.5v*5; 17.5v, max voltage Em = 4v*5; 20v. Two 9V batteries would provide 18V in series, E. voltage across the resistor Et-E = 0.5v, then the resistance needed is 0.5v/20mA = 0.025v/mA. Does that sound about right?

Comment: The math is OK but 0.5V/0.02A = 25 ohms is the resistor you would ask for. HOWEVER if the LEDs you get have Vmax=4V ... 18V < 20V so no light. Which is why Vmax determines your supply ... in your case, 27V and take it from there.

Comment: Ok I think I understand better now. I'll move to 4 instead of 5 leds,  with 2v/0.02a = 100 ohms resistor. You have been so much help and it really is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Closer, and given 18V, 4 LEDS is a better choice. But... what happens with "typical" LEDS and that 100 ohm resistor? I chose "max" voltage for selecting battery and "typical" volts for selecting resistor for a reason...

Comment: I'm trying, but I don't fully understand the implications. With typical usage at 3.5v the ohm doubles. So I think your saying at typical usage levels with 100ohms the amps would also double, and be too high?

Comment: You got it right. But to explain: when designing, you have to take variability into account. 100 ohms could over-stress "typical" LEDs (with a fresh battery!) though you might get away with it. 200 ohms would be safe under all combinations of LED at a (surprisingly small) cost in brightness (and more battery life!) The answer is a shorthand process to accomplish that : the comments explain why.